# Homotopic and Smoothly Homotopic Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

So I learn about these two things today. Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and $f_1,f_2$ be smooth maps from $M$ to $N$

Def: $f_1$ and $f_2$ are HOMOTOPIC if there exists a a smooth map $H: [0,1]\times M\to N$ s.t. $H(0,m)=f_1(m)$ and $H(1,m)=f_2(m)$.

Def: $f_1$ and $f_2$ are SMOOTHLY HOMOTOPIC if there exists a a smooth map $H: \mathbb{R} \times M\to N$ s.t. $H(0,m)=f_1(m)$ and $H(1,m)=f_2(m)$.

I want to ask what is the relation between these two. I understand that if they are smoothly homotopic, then they are homotopic since we can restrict the homotopy map. What about the other way around? If we have a homotopy on $[0,1]$, can we extend it to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Just send every number $\ge1$ to $1$ and every number $\le0$ to $0$.

Comment: would that preserve smoothness?

Comment: moreover, if we can really do it, they these two definitions are equivalent, right? why complicate things?

Comment: Usually, two maps $f_0, f_1$ are said to be homotopic if there is a **continuous** map $H: [0,1]\times M\to N$ such that $H(0,x)=f_0(x), H(1,x)=f_1(x)$. In fact the notion of homotopy is defined for general topological spaces. What you defined is a **smooth** homotopy. There is a theorem which says that two smooth maps between smooth manifolds are homotopic if and only if they are smoothly homotopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $H:[0,1]\times M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth homotopy. We are working here with a manifold with boundary, so what does it mean that this map is smooth?

Well, we have to recall, what does it mean that a map $f:H^+\rightarrow N$ is smooth, where $H^+\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a halfspace. One of the definitions (that I am aware of) is that there exists an open subset $H^+\subseteq U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ extends to a smooth map $\tilde{f}:U\rightarrow N$. If we apply this definition to a homotopy $H:[0,1]\times M\rightarrow N$ and use compactness of $[0,1]$, we derive that there exists open subset $[0,1]\subseteq U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $H$ can be extended to a smooth map $\tilde{H}:U\times M\rightarrow N$. We may assume that $U$ is an open interval containing $[0,1]$. Next we can pick a diffeomorphism $d:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U$ such that $d_{\mid [0,1]}= 1_{[0,1]}$ and finally we define 
$$F = \tilde{H}\cdot (d\times 1_M):\mathbb{R}\times M\rightarrow N$$
This is a homotopy in the other sense extending $H$.