# homotopic $C^{2}$ paths are $C^{2}$ homotopic?

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces, homotopy-theory, closed-form, approximation-theory

The context is the following :

**Proposition** : Let $E$ be a real Banach space, $\Omega \subseteq E$ open,
$\omega \in C^{1}(\Omega,E^{*})$ a closed 1-form. Let be $\gamma_{0},\gamma_{1}$ $C^{2}$ two $\gamma$-homotopic paths with fixed endpoints. It holds that $\int_{\gamma_{0}} \omega = \int_{\gamma_{1}} \omega$.

I do understand the proof I have of the above statement, which goes on defining $\phi(s) = \int_{\gamma(s,\bullet)} \omega$ and prooving that it's constant;

What I don't get is the assumption (without loss of generality) that $\gamma$, the homotopy between $\gamma_{0},\gamma_{1}$, a priori $C^{0}$, can actually be considered $C^{2}$.

Are there any known approximation Thorems for this? I thought about using Stone-Weierstrass or trying to approximate the homotopy with piecewise $C^{2}$ polygonals taken in appropriate dense set, failing.

I found some references of what I'm looking for only between manifolds and smooth maps in the following links, but since manifold are above my knowledge i didn't find find any solution.

Any help or comment would be appreciated,thanks.

[Smooth homotopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028457/smooth-homotopy), 
[Homotopic and Smoothly Homotopic Manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462482/homotopic-and-smoothly-homotopic-manifolds)

Comment: I suppose $E$ is finite dimensional, am I right?

Comment: @Caffeine It was not specified, but if it helps we can start with E beeing finite dimensional

Comment: Could you go into details,for the finite dimensional case ? @Caffeine

Comment: you could use a generalized version of Bernstein polynomials for Banach spaces which also keep the endpoints fixed